# How to ask Mathematica to show the results of two domains with different colors in the given code?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to ask Mathematica to show the results of two different domains (dom1 and dom2) with different colors

```
dom2 = Table[3 n, {n, 10/3}];
dom1 = Array[If[FractionalPart[#/3] == 0, Nothing, #] &, 10];

f[n_] := Piecewise[{{n \[Pi], MemberQ[n]@dom1}, {1, MemberQ[n]@dom2}}]
data = Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 1, 10}];

ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 6}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ListLogPlot[data, 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 Mesh -> {Join[Thread[{dom1, Red}], Thread[{dom2, Green}]]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap each point in `data` with `Style`:

```
styleddata = data /. {a : {Alternatives @@ dom1, _} :> Style[a, Red], 
    a : {Alternatives @@ dom2, _} :> Style[a, Green]};

ListLogPlot[styleddata, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

or separate `data` into two sets as in Bob Hanlon's answer:

```
ListLogPlot[Cases[{Alternatives @@ #, _}] @ data & /@ {dom1, dom2}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dom2 = Table[3 n, {n, 10/3}];

dom1 = Array[If[FractionalPart[#/3] == 0, Nothing, #] &, 10];

data1 = {#, # Pi} & /@ dom1;

data2 = {#, 1} & /@ dom2;
```

With different colors and shapes

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
```

[image]